# What is an appropriate and meaningful substitute to "Thank God" (from an agnostic perspective)?

Tags: single-word-requests, religion

Raised as a "Mormon" I was taught that saying "Thank God" is blasphemy and sacrilegious. As an agnostic adult, I struggle to replace the phrase w/ something that honestly represents my feelings w/o offending anyone while at the same time, holding to my beliefs. Seems simple, I know. I could be thanking ANY God. I don't want that. I'd like my audience (in whatever capacity) to understand that I'm thankful to whatever "force", but I'm not choosing sides.

I know its seems silly, but its important to me.

Comment: Did you try searching for synonyms of "thank god"? Perhaps this thread will also help: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/321750/what-non-religious-expressions-can-i-use-instead-of-thank-god

Comment: Thanks are usually expressed toward persons, or toward powers or forces with some aspect of personhood about them. If you don't recognize any such, why feel thanks at all? You could just express relief that circumstances are in your favor.

Comment: ... yes, "What a relief!" is a common expletive.

Comment: "Thank Heavens!" is the usual euphemism that doesn't mention any Being.

Comment: How do you distinguish your god from any god?? Why do you say raised as a "Mormon"?? In the Western World, god is usually construed as the God recognized in Christianity or Judaism. Not some Greek god pictured on a pedestal in a museum. Thank goodness! Thank heavens.

Comment: Who or what do you want to thank, or who or what do you want people to think you are thanking, or who do you not want to be thanking? If you just want to express relief there are various non-verbal ways of doing that (e.g. exhaling).

Comment: You could paraphrase Mr. Spock and gratefully say, "Random chance appears to have operated in my favor."

Comment: Many atheists and gnostics still employ idioms that mention God. Since they're idioms, they're not interpreted literally. E.g. they'll say "bless you" when someone sneezes.

Comment: I don't understand how thanking God could be blasphemy or sacrilege. If you believe in God, by saying "Thank God", you would really mean to thank God, so it's not blasphemy or sacrilege. If you don't believe in God, by saying "Thank God", you don't really mean to thank God, but you're simply using a fixed expression. No blasphemy or sacrilege intended.

Comment: Probably not helpful, but "Thank Heavens" implies the same.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest alternative is "Thank goodness," which [Cambridge notes](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/thank-god-goodness-heaven-s-etc) is a synonym for "Thank God."

Comment: I'm guessing *Hallelujah* is out then? :)

Answer (score 1):

Another option is, "Thank my lucky stars!"